# I want to set up email forms on my website using gmail Smtp, i need help though

Tags: smtp

I just want to start by saying I HAVE ZERO! and I MEAN ZERO- technology intuition whatsoever. That being said, I've started a new business and I needed to make a website as its mostly online. I'm a student and I'm on a really tight budjet so I found a free website builder called https://infinityfree.net/ .

Now, I've set up a form on the site and it runs on SMTP, but I need help configuring it so that the completed forms get sent to my gmail.
On infinity free " you cannot use PHP mail on InfinityFree" to send your email, but I am allowed to use email with Gmail SMTP. 
The properties for the form I wnat on my website have a few boxes that I need to fill in, I've looked online and I know theres a difference between TLS and SSL, ( I've heard that TLS is safer, but I don't really care which one the website will use so long as it works) .and that they have numbers that go with them like TLS- 465.
 I filled it in once and It worked- then my computer re-set and I havent been able to re-fill it in again, its getting really quite upsetting and  I've tried asking infinityfree with help filling it in, but the admin are VERY RUDE, really unhelpful and quite patronizing- I'm finding this all especially hard with my limited computer knowledge, - i'm literally close to tears.

The picture is of the setting I need to fill in,for the form.  I just really need help knowing what goes in each box...If anyone could guide me through it, I'd be VERY much appreciative.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFGd3.png)

Answer (score 0):

- I am pretty sure it goes like this:
- Host: smtp.gmail.com
- Username: (Your email)
- Password: (Your email's password)
- Port: SSL: 587 or TLS:

But I do not know the port for non TLS and SSL websites as you refer.

If I helped you pls like me!